# Mute youtube video that has to be embedded via HTML iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

**Problem**

I'm working with a site where the developer coded an embedded youtube video to change via a script altering the iframe's src tag.

**I need to mute this element, and while I'm aware that a few libraries allow me to embed a video via script with the option of muting, I'm unaware of any way to use those methods without having to rescript everything that has been done on the youtube player. What's the best option here?**

**element**

```
<iframe id="tv" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9NFUgVa68hw?autoplay=1&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&disablekb=1&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**script**

```
var channel1 = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/dFU6Cy4Hd5A?autoplay=1&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&disablekb=1&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1";

$("#channel-1").click(function(){
$("#tv").attr("src", channel1);
$(".mid-bar").text("TNT");
});
```

The above is just one module of the script; there are 22 channels.

Again, I'm trying to mute the embedded video without having to rescript the src changes. How can this be done?

Comment: Looking back, I used to ask some pretty bad questions here.

Answer (score 2):

I understand you don't wish to change the src, however, if you append `enablejsapi=1` you can then use javascript to mute the video by calling `object.mute()`

Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Playback_controls